# Nodejs http request timeout handler called even after 200 status received

Tags: node.js, https, request, timeout

I'm using a small url-monitor from Julien Blanc, and I'm trying to figure out why my req.setTimeout and req.on("timeout") are called even after successful response is received from the server.
It would be easier to write this using axios, but I'd like to know why this happens in this scenario (or even better, how can I remove the timeout handler in success/fail scenarios):

```
async testUrl(url, urlIndex) {
    const self = this;
    const obj = urlp.parse(url);
    let req = null;

    console.log(self.counter++, url);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log({ req });
      if (obj.protocol == "https:" || obj.protocol == "http:") {
        if (obj.port == null) {
          obj.port = obj.protocol == "https:" ? "443" : "80";
        }

        process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"; // Ignore self-signed certificate error

        req = https.request(
          {
            host: obj.hostname,
            port: obj.port,
            method: "GET",
            path: obj.path,
            agent: false,
          },
          (res) => {
            if (
              res.statusCode === 200 ||
              res.statusCode === 301 ||
              res.statusCode === 302
            ) {
              self.emit("available", self.message(url, res.statusCode));
            } else {
              self.emit("unavailable", self.message(url, res.statusCode));
            }

            req.end();
            resolve(1);
          }
        );

        req.on("finish", function () {
          console.log("request_end");
          resolve(1);
        });

        req.setTimeout(self.timeout, function () {
          console.log(urlIndex);
          req.abort();
        });

        req.on("timeout", function () {
          self.emit("req_timeout", {
            code: null,
            url: url,
            message: "Request timeout",
          });
        });

        req.on("error", function (err) {
          self.emit("error", {
            code: null,
            url: url,
            message: "Host unavailable",
          });
        });

        req.end();
      } else {
        self.emit("error", {
          code: null,
          url: url,
          message: "Unknown protocol (http & https only)",
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same problem

Comment: I moved to Axios, it fits my needs